# Java jTextPane one line with regular and bold Text missplaced

Tags: java, text, jtextpane

I have a TextPane using the StyledDocument.
If a message is typed it first adds current time and the other Users IP into the Document
After that a custom message entered by the User is added right behind that in bold.

Apparently the problem is that bold takes up more space and makes it misplaced resulting in this:
[image]
<-   Currently So the code used for this process is the following:

```js
public void addText(String msg) {

 long timeMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
 Date instant = new Date(timeMS);
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 String time = sdf.format(instant);
 SimpleAttributeSet bold = new SimpleAttributeSet();
 StyleConstants.setBold(bold, true);
 try {
     StyledDocument doc = getChat().getStyledDocument();
     doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), time + ": " + Client.getClient().getPartnerIP() + " >>", null);
     doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), msg + "", bold);
     JScrollBar sb = getChatScroller().getVerticalScrollBar();
     sb.setValue(sb.getMaximum());
 } catch (BadLocationException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
    }
```

I know this could be easily fixed using the htmlEditorKit, but I don't want to use the htmlEditorKit.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the posted code. Please add SSCCE example to let us run and reproduce the problem,

Comment: I got it fixed by using the HTMLEditorKit and formatting the whole String in one html line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventho I said I don't want to use the HTMLEditorKit i used it now because it was the only fix I could find.

This is my current working method:

```
public void addMsg(String msg, String from) {
String formattedMessage = String.format("%s%s<font color=#FF0000 size=5><b>%s</b></font>\n", from, (from == getUserName() ? " >>" : " &lt;&lt;"), msg);
addText(formattedMessage, true);
}
```

And dont forget to set the EditorKit on the TextPane!

```
chat.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
```